# DOJO form FilteringSelect allow user entered data

Tags: javascript, dojo

I want to create a form with FilteringSelect element and would be great if use could enter custom value. I tried to do that with comboBox but without success (it sends always value - tried all available tricks).
With FilteringSelect I already tried to set up custom Validator (function(value,constraints){return false;}) but it still doesnt now allow me to send custom value.

BTW: Im creating a form with Zend_Dojo_Form .

Answer (score 0):

I made small work around ;)

```
dijit.byId('nameOfTheWidget').item.value;
```

assigned in onChange event to hidden input.
Tricky but works as I wanted.
It means I made it with ComboBox